# Regex match token with argument

Tags: regex, arguments, token, braces

A token can be like this `{num}` or `{num:2}` (2 being an arg)

I would like to achieve matching like this:

```
// no args
[0] = num

// args (anything after the colon and before the closing brace as one match is fine)
[0] = num
[1] = 2
```

I managed to match anything in the braces that was easy but my regex is too noob to get anything more complex than that! Thanks.

FYI I am using javascript and `\{(.*?)\}` matches all the contents within.

Comment: a) Which language or tool are you using? b) please show us your own attempt anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
\{(.*?)(?::(.*?))?\}
```

And a test:

```
> '{foo:bar}'.match(/\{(.*?)(?::(.*?))?\}/)
["{foo:bar}", "foo", "bar"]
> '{foo}'.match(/\{(.*?)(?::(.*?))?\}/)
["{foo}", "foo", undefined]
```

- `(.*?)` non-greedily matches the first group.
- `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group. It's just like a regular capturing group, but it doesn't get captured.
- `:(.*?)` captures the stuff after the colon.
- `?` makes that last group (which contains the colon and the second capturing group) optional.

Comment: This worked great and thanks for the explanation it makes sense. I was trying to match with brackets within the brackets but was unaware of non-capturing groups and how to make it optional etc so was stabbing in the dark